# Problema redirigir a otra pagina en una peticion AJAX a un script PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, headers

Estoy haciendo una petición AJAX a un script PHP donde se le pasa unas variables, hace una serie de consultas MYSQL y si tiene éxito quiero desde el script PHP redirigir a otra pagina con `Location` :'algún lugar'.

El problema son las cabeceras en el script PHP. Si las pongo después del `Location` la petición AJAX no encuentra el archivo PHP, y si el `Location` lo pongo después de los `Header` entonces no me redirecciona.

Pongo el código PHP para que lo veáis:

```
function redirigirRegistro(){
    $ruta = 'http://localhost/miweb/valencia/registrarse.php';
    header("Location: $ruta");   
    die();
}

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

A la función `redirigirRegistro` se la llama después hacer unas consultas. Entonces si pongo la función antes de las cabeceras me la petición responde

> error: 302 Found.

Si lo la función la pongo después los header el Location no me funciona.

Puedo solucionarlo en la petición AJAX si tiene exicto con redirecionamiento con JQUERY.

```
 }).complete(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
              $(location).attr('href','http://localhost/miweb/Valencia/registrarse.php');  
            });
```

Pero no me gusta y quería hacerlo desde el script PHP.¿Como podría hacerlo?

Comment: Ya tienes la solución con jQuery.

Comment: No es posible desde PHP, porque, siendo petición AJAX, el navegador no interpreta los encabezados `Location`, solo los referentes a contenido. Aunque podrías intentar obtenerlo, como sugieren en [respuestas de esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223946/how-to-get-response-header-location-from-jquery-get/41929637)

Comment: Gracias Roger así lo he hecho.